# debug shopware6 document pdf

Tags: shopware, shopware6

How do we debug the shopware6 pdf generation? A {{ dump() }} will not work, the pdf is not generated. We get an error then:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
```

Are there any possibilities? Maybe can we get the html instead of pdf to find what we are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [`OrderDocumentCriteriaFactory`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/c5caf3a0ec944e0caec347d3fb3d17950a499520/src/Core/Checkout/Document/Renderer/OrderDocumentCriteriaFactory.php) for which association of the order are available in the template. If you plan on working with an association, be mindful that they must be added to that criteria and may be nullable as well. Adding a sanity check too many is preferable to assuming all orders will come with every association.

Also see the [`DocumentTemplateRenderer`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/ee97793475d68d2ced24bed414f8a15442f98073/src/Core/Checkout/Document/Twig/DocumentTemplateRenderer.php). If an exception is thrown while rendering the twig template, this is where the exception could be caught for further debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [WYSIWYG Document Editor](https://store.shopware.com/en/appli81810362453/wysiwyg-document-editor-pdf-design-invoices-delivery-notes-credit-notes-storno-bills.html) to customize your Shopware 6 Documents visually via Drag & Drop. You can browse and search all available variables in the left sidebar. This is a lot easier than using Twig in general and saves a lot of time.

[image: Variable Search in the Shopware 6 WYSIWYG Document Editor App]

I am the developer, which created the WYSIWYG Document Editor Shopware 6 App. Feel free to ask me any questions about the App. I am happy to help you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I would suggest to add a disclosure, that you are working for the company who made the module :-)
https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion "you must disclose your affiliation in your post."

Comment: Thank you for this hint. I didn't knew this. This was my first answer, which i posted on Stackoverflow. I added a disclosure now :)